# I'm trying to have 2 check box columns before other columns in DataGrid

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

I am trying to have 2 check boxes in rows from first 2 columns and rest with some text. With my code I have the text boxes at each row but at the last 2 columns.

I want to be able to put my check boxes before the text entries.

I tried changing order of the code but I cannot get the result I desire.

What could be wrong with my code here?

```
        dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 4;
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Delete";
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Edit";
        dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "User Name";
        dataGridView1.Columns[3].Name = "Password";

        DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn delete = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
        DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn edit = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(delete);
        delete.HeaderText = "Delete";
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(edit);
        edit.HeaderText = "Edit";

        string[] row;

        row = new string[] { "1", "Product 1", "1000", "1" };
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
        row = new string[] { "2", "Product 4", "2000", "2" };
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
        row = new string[] { "3", "Product 5", "3000", "3" };
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
        row = new string[] { "4", "Product 6", "4000", "4" };
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
```

Comment: need more explation from your side

Comment: @rahularyansharma, I have updater my OP. But let me know what you like to know.

Comment: You are adding the columns twice in two different ways.  Pick one.  And keep in mind you can also add them in the designer...

Comment: where is username and password in ( "1", "Product 1", "1000", "1" )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DataGridView.Rows.Add() function takes an array of objects.  The object type you provide should depend on the type of each column.

Therefore, if you set up your columns properly, you should be able to write:

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[] { true, false, "user", "password" });
```

In your original code you added the columns twice in two different ways.  Pick one method of adding the columns.

Comment: Seems like this work. But I rather use designer to create the layout, easier that way.

Answer (score -1):

See the following...

```
        dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 4;
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Delete";
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Edit";
        dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "User Name";
        dataGridView1.Columns[3].Name = "Password";

        DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn delete = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
        DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn edit = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
        dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(0,delete);
        //dataGridView1.Columns.Add(delete);
        delete.HeaderText = "Delete";
        //dataGridView1.Columns.Add(edit);
        dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(1,edit);
        edit.HeaderText = "Edit";


        string[] row;

        row = new string[] {"false","false", "1", "Product 1", "1000", "1" };
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
        row = new string[] { "false", "false", "2", "Product 4", "2000", "2" };
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
        row = new string[] { "false", "false", "3", "Product 5", "3000", "3" };
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
        row = new string[] { "false", "false", "4", "Product 6", "4000", "4" };
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
```